# Change management in ESB (servicemix, mule, jboss, ...)

Tags: wso2, mule, apache-servicemix, jboss-esb, wso2-esb

I am wondering if any of the open source ESB provides strong change management capabilities:

- ability to version services, components, rollback changes, compare
  changes.
- And if it could log which user has made changes and what is the
  change to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an [ESB ability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus#Salient_characteristics). 
But usually ESBs can behave like app containers (as in David A Chappell's Enterprise Service Bus [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006754) chapter 6). So the app/modules can be versioned.

For instance: Mule ESB can behave like a container. Mule provides a maven archetype for creating mule apps. Those apps can be commited to an version control repository. The hot deployment abilities of the container, should be enough to "rollback" changes.

Comment: Yeah. I see. Thanks. You have knowledge of SOA governance software? For example: Mule Galaxy, Petals Master. They provide change management right? is it over killed to use it just for the change management part.

Comment: To be honest I'm not a regular Mule Galaxy user, but by the experience of the tests I've done with it. It should comply your requirements.

Comment: Please consider to close the question if it is answered.